# Is it possible to add files in-place to a tar archive?

Tags: tar

Suppose I have two files A and B that are 50 GB each, along with about 100 other files of negligible size. I only have 120 GB of disk space (of which 100 GB is taken up by files A and B). I want to create a tar archive containing files A and B and the 100 other files. Is it possible to achieve this with less than 20 GB of disk space remaining?

The tar archive will be uploaded to a long-term cloud storage solution (e.g. Amazon S3 Glacier Deep Archive, Google Cloud Archive Storage, etc.).

Comment: Do you want A and B to remain? (In some filesystems this question is not stupid in general.) If not then I guess a careful approach with `kill -s STOP`, `fallocate --punch-hole`(?), `kill -s CONT` may work. Tricky but doable, I think. Is the problem in question a one-time task? so "manual" solution is acceptable? Or is your ultimate goal to create a fully automatic script?

Comment: If your files are fluffy enough, you could compress the tar before it gets saved to disk.  Another way around this is to write the tar to a different device, possibly over the network.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski A and B should not remain. Manual solutions are acceptable as this is a one-time task.

Comment: Why do you need the have the tar file in the first place?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani It is for archival purposes. The tar archive will be uploaded to a long-term cloud storage solution (e.g. Amazon S3 Glacier Deep Archive, Google Cloud Archive Storage, etc.).

Comment: Flux, why not simply put both files there, separately?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is for organizational purposes. Admittedly, I have simplified the problem somewhat. In reality, I have about 100 files I want to place into a single tar archive because they belong together. Nearly all the files are of negligible size, except for two gigantic files (referred to as A and B in the question). In this scheme, it does not make sense to place A and B separately.

Comment: please don't only comment, but **edit** your question to contain all that data. Please don't oversimplify! This is now the third time you've invalidated an answer that I was writing by giving info that you could have given right at the start.

Comment: I mean, you don't only simplify, you straight up lie: two files of 50GB each is simply a different problem than 1000 files. Seriously, don't do that. You're the one asking, so describe your actual problem, not some other problem that you assume might have the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

> The tar archive will be uploaded to a long-term cloud storage solution (e.g. Amazon S3 Glacier Deep Archive, Google Cloud Archive Storage, etc.).

Ah! So you really never need the tar archive on your disk!

Instead, you can create the tar archive on the fly while uploading it to amazon S3 or whatever. Plus, you *really* want compression, because you're paying by the volume.

Solution should be quite straightforward:

```
tar c fileA fileB | aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/backup.tar -
    : :     :     :           :                        :
    : :     :     :           :                        \- read data from stdin
    : :     :     :           \- How to call the object
    : :     :     \- unix pipe: the stdout of the
    : :     :        tar command becoms the stdin
    : :     :        of the aws command.
    : \-----\- files to be compressed
    \--compression command
```

Personally, especially when you say you've got thousands of very small files, the overhead of the `tar` format becomes very significant. I'd recommend using

```
tar c --zstd file1 file2 … file1000 | aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/backup.tar.zst -
```

to, on the fly, compress the data. It saves you upload time, paid space on your cloud hoster, and is generally the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

## Remark

this solution is not appropriate, as the asker later pointed out it's neither about two large files nor about actually storing the tar archive locally. But seeing that it still addresses the original title of the question, I thought I'd leave it up for posterity.

## Answer

So, problem: You can't "free" the space used by a file before you've finished reading it; so, the standard approaches to put files into a `tar` archive cannot work, because that's basically:

- read the properties of the first file (name, length, owner, etc)
- write the header containing that information to the .tar file at position 0; that header has a length of 512 bytes
- copy the content of the first file after the header, zero-padded to the next multiple of 512 bytes (padding with zeros)
- read the properties of the second file
- write the header for that second file after the end of the first file
- copy the contents of the second file, aligned at the next multiple of 512 B
- finally, delete both files

As you can see, tar archives can very simply be concatenated. Sadly, you can't even copy the contents of one file to a tar archive, then delete that, then archive the next one, because you'll run out of space before the first finished writing (and there's no POSIX way of truncating the *start* of a file that you've already read). So, Kamil's approach from the comments above does not work.

So, as long as you're not a file system that supports reflinking *parts* of files, this is impossible. (The only Linux file systems that currently , June 2021, support that, are XFS and btrfs. However, you'll have to write that software yourself; you'll want to research `man ioctl_ficlonerange`, which allows you to share the memory used by the original files and the archived files.)

---

However, having a 100 GB tar file sounds pretty useless on its own; what are you going to do with that? You'll copy it to some other device or over network, in which case you *never* have to have it on your own drive!

You'd just create that tar archive on the fly, instead of first generating it on your hard drive, then copying it. `tar` does not care whether it writes the result into a file, a block device (`tar` is short for *T*ape *Ar*chive, anyway!) or a network socket.

So, seeing what you want to do is impossible¹ might be depressing - but I think you might be solving a non-problem.

¹ unless your files are both on the same XFS or btrfs file system, and you know what an `ioctl` is and are willing to write code

Comment: If your filesystem actually *happens* to be btrfs or XFS, you've worked with file descriptors and ioctls before and you'd be interested in implementing this, let me know, I can try to point you in directions.

Comment: The filesystem in question is ext4, and my knowledge of UNIX facilities is subpar.

Comment: well, in the case of ext4, there's simply no non-data-copying approach. But, as said, I think the silver lining at the horizon is that you probably don't need to create the tar on the same disk you're on, What are you going to do with that tar archive?

Comment: The tar archive will be uploaded to a long-term cloud storage solution (e.g. Amazon S3 Glacier Deep Archive, Google Cloud Archive Storage, etc.).

Comment: That's crucial information! I'm adding this to your question.